# I want to know what effects were used on these digital drawings I saw on Twitter

Tags: drawing, digital

I was browsing through some artists pages on Twitter and I found these images:

[image] [image]

<sub>From [this Twitter post](https://twitter.com/vencyslao/status/1163466736177491969).</sub>

I'm new at digital drawing, so I don't know how to ask, or what to look for in order to find out what it is, so I have two questions:

What are those blue lines outlining the line art of the first image? Is it done manually with a brush, or is it some effect layer?

Also, what is it that makes the image look "granulated"?

I'm not sure if I'm being clear enough, so let me know if you need more information. Thanks!

Comment: Looks like water colors (or simulated water colors).

Comment: It's probably not digital other than scanning. My guess it its actually drawn and painted manually. Grain is introduced by the medium being used to paint on.

Comment: @ZachSaucier, nice of you to edit, but the images are so small that you can hardly see the outline effect and the noise which is visible on the original images.

Comment: @Wolff Click on them and remove the last "m" from the URL then. Also the link is still there...

Comment: If you found the artist's twitter feed, why don't you ask the artist directly?? For sure he'll know exactly what effect is that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't tell you exactly how this was made. To me it looks like it was digitally painted somehow. Especially if I compare it to other images from the same artist.

Here are some tips on how to achieve the same look.

I made a quick sketch with black outlines multiplied onto some simple fills:

[image]

The effect on the outline looks like *Red/Cyan Fringe*, which is something you actually normally want to *remove* from photos. I use *Filter > Lens Correction...* and set the *Fix Red/Cyan Fringe* to *-100%*:

[image]

Which results in this:

[image]

This looks alright, but a little subtle, so I repeat the effect 3 more times using <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>:

[image]

That's more like it!

The granulated look can be achieved in many different, more or less sophisticated, ways. Here I simply flatten the image and use *Filter > Noise > Add Noise...* to add some subtle *Uniform* noise:

[image]

I think the result looks similar to your reference:

[image]

Experiment with the settings to fine-tune the effect.